# Covariance for a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, covariance, bivariate-distributions

I have a question concerning the bivariate normal distribution where I have been able to prove that the first covariance we are asked for is equal to $0$, but was not sure if this would be implying that the second covariance has to also equal $0$.

This is the problem:

[image]

I was able to prove that $Cov(Y-\rho X,X)=0$ and I know that $E(X^3)=0$, so with this, I can say that $E[(Y-\rho X)^{10}X^3]=Cov((Y-\rho X)^{10},X^3)$, however, I don't recall having any statement concerning the covariance with powers over the random variables. I would assume the covariance is equal to $0$, but am honestly not convinced of why would this be the case (if it is indeed equal to $0$).

Any key observation over this would be very useful.

Thank you

Comment: [For two random variables that are jointly normal, zero-covariance implies independence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just to clarify, if we have any natural numbers as our exponents, this will continue to be the case, right? is that the fact that we take $Y-\rho X$ sort of made me doubt for a moment.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are independent r.v.s, then so are $f(A)$ and $g(B)$ for any functions $f,g$.

Comment: Thanks once again @r.e.s. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you proved that $\mathbb{Cov}[Y-\rho X,X]=0$ you are done because (using the fact given in the text) this is equivalent to prove that $(Y-\rho X)\perp\!\!\!\perp X $ thus

$$\mathbb{E}[(Y-\rho X)^{10}X^3]=\mathbb{E}[(Y-\rho X)^{10}]\cdot\mathbb{E}[X^3]=0$$

Being $\mathbb{E}[X^{2n+1}]=0$, $ \forall n$